# javascript flexible argument for curry function

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding curry function..
I know that if I have this simple curry function:

```
const greeting = (greet) => {
  return (name) => {
    return `${greet} ${name}`;
  };
};
```

I can call `greeting('Hello')('John')` and it will return **Hello John**.

Is there a way to make it flexible say between 1 parameter and 2 parameters, ex: with
the above greeting function, is there a way for me to call `greeting('Hello')` and `greeting('Hello')('John')` and it will return **Hello** and **Hello John** respectively?

I know that I can do it with `greeting('Hello')()` and `greeting('Hello')('John')` but I was just trying to avoid breaking changes because I already have a greeting method and want to extend it using curry function, so I want it to also accept greeting('Hello') without the extra () at the end...

thanks

Comment: No. `greeting("Hello John")` and `greeting("Hello")` both only pass one argument and will return a function. You'd still need to call it and possibly handle an `undefined` value for `name`

Comment: rephrasing my question, hoping that it will make things clearer..

Comment: For `greeting(a)(b)` to return a string, `greeting(a)` must return a function, not a string, so `greeting(a)` can't return a string.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of only one option that works by coercing the curried function into a string. This won't change the return value but it will allow you to get the result you want depending on context.

```js
const greeting = greet => Object.defineProperties(
  name => `${greet} ${name}`, // curried
  {
    toString: {
      value: () => greet,
    },
    valueOf: {
      value: () => greet
    }
  }
)

console.log(typeof greeting("Hello")) // function, not string
console.log(`${greeting("Hello")}`) // note the string context
console.log(`${greeting("Hello")("World")}`)
```

---

If you need the return value to actually toggle between a function and a string however, the answer is *no*.

In order for `greeting("Hello")("John")` to return a string, `greeting("Hello")` **must** return a function.

There is no way to tell within `greeting()` how the curried function is going to be called so you cannot detect whether or not to return a function or a string.

Think of it this way, `greeting("Hello")("John")` is just a short version of...

```js
const fn = greeting("Hello")

// later or maybe never...

fn("John")
```

You simply don't know how, when or even if that curried function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way? Sure. But why? because won't that be "un-currying" it? And you will have to modify the function of-course.

You can always do something like this just get the output your asked for:

```js
const greeting = (greet) => {
  const split = greet.split(" ");
  if(split.length > 1) 
       return `${split[0]} ${split[1]}`;
  else return (name) => {
    return `${greet} ${name}`;
  };
};
```

Comment: hmm.. i see.. i guess it's kind of a no then.. i have an existing function and i was trying to try having a curry function for an extension of that function, but I do not want it to be a breaking changes where all the call of the existing function (which is currently like function()) should be called like function()()...

Answer (score -1):

If you use a helper function for currying, you can get a similar behavior automatically. For example, take the implementation at [javascript.info/currying-partials](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)

```
function curry(func) {

    return function curried(...args) {
        if (args.length >= func.length) {
            return func.apply(this, args);
        } else {
            return function(...args2) {
                return curried.apply(this, args.concat(args2));
            }
        } 
    };
}
```

You can define

```
const greeting = curry((greet, name) => `${greet} ${name}`)
```

and call

```
greeting("Hello", "John")
```

or

```
greeting("Hello")("John")
```

Comment: ah, yeah, was looking into that as well, but I guess what I want to do is if I call greeting('Hello') it should return Hello

Comment: The problem is that for ‘greeting(“Hello”)(“John”)’ to work you have to have ‘greeting(“Hello”)’ return a function.